# How to get the subclass of a class by soot？

Tags: java, soot

I can get the superclass of a class by `SootClass.getSuperclass()`, but I don't know how to get its subclass.

Have I need to load the subclass first? There is no `getSubclass()` function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply get "the subclass", because there can be many such classes, subclassing one specific class or implementing a certain interface.

I suppose, you would have to iterate over all classes in the scene
and for each such class check if its superclass is the given class/interface.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use Scene.v().getHierarchy() or Scene.v().getFastHierarchy()